# Using the method of Frobenius to solve a differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following differential equation by using the method of Frobenius. I'm however, having some trouble in doing so, I was hoping someone could help me out.

> $2ty''+(1+t)y'-2y=0$

**ATTEMPT:**
First of all, we need to control if we can actually use Frobenius' method. By looking at $2ty''$ we can easily conclude that $t=0$ is the only singular point of the differential equation. Then we need to control whether $t \cdot (1+t)$ and $ t^2 \cdot -2 $ are both analytic at $t=0$, which is true. Therefore, we can indeed use the method of Frobenius.

We let $y$ be of the form $y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n \cdot t^{n+r}$, then we can get the following by differentiating:

> $y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n \cdot t^{n+r}$
>
> $y'=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r)a_n \cdot t^{n+r-1}$
>
> $y''=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r)(n+r-1)a_n \cdot t^{n+r-2}$

We now plug these back in our differential equation:

$\begin{align}
2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r)(n+r-1)a_n \cdot t^{n+r-1}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r)a_n \cdot t^{n+r-1} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r)a_n \cdot t^{n+r} - 2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n \cdot t^{n+r} =\\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n[2(n+r)(n+r-1)+n+r]t^{n+r-1}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n-1}[n+r-3]t^{n+r-1} =\\
[a_0(2r(r-1))+ra_0]t^r+[2a_1(r+1)(r)+a_1(r+1)+a_0(r-2)]t^{r+1}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty[a_n[2(n+r)(n+r-1)+n+r] + a_{n-1}(n+r-3)]t^{n+r-1} = 0
\end{align}$
So then, out of the first term of the sum (since it has to be 0, as the sum is equal to zero), we can solve for r, which gives us $r=0$ or $r=\frac{1}{2}$, since $a_0$ is assumed to be non-zero. Otherwise it would just change the index of r.

Then, we set $a_0$ to be $1$. and we can solve for $a_0$ by using the second term. $r=0$ gives us that $a_1$ has to be $2$. $r= \frac{1}{2}$ gives us that $a_1$ has to be equal to $\frac{1}{2}$. The last term of the equation above gives us the recurrent relationship. I believe that when we have the recurrent relationship, by plugging in the two different $a_1$ values, we will get two linearly independent solutions for the differential equation and therefore we'll get the general solution of the differential equation. I'm not able however to find this recurrent relationship.

**QUESTIONS:** I'm having quite a bit of trouble with using this method to solve differential equations, so here are a couple of questions I want to ask:

1. Is it always necessary to write out the first and second term of the sum, as to get the values for $r$ and $a_1$?
2. Is it okay to just set $a_0$ equal to 1?
3. In the sum, I chose to change the powers of t equal to n+r-1 as to factor these powers out, I have also set these to n+r in a previous attempt, however, that I couldn't solve. Is there a general approach as to how to set these powers? Do you always set them at the lowest power of t in the total differential equation?
4. Is this a correct and efficient manner to solve such a problem with Frebenius' method? Or is there some work that could be omitted?

Thanks for your time,

K. Kamal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n[2(n+r)(n+r-1)+n+r]t^{n+r-1} +\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n[n+r-2]t^{n+r}=0$$ $$a_0[2r^2-2r+r]t^{r-1} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[2(n+r)(n+r-1)+n+r]a_nt^{n+r-1}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}[n+r-2]a_nt^{n+r}=0$$ $$a_0[2r^2-r]t^{r-1}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}[2(n+r+1)(n+r)+n+r]a_{n+1}t^{n+r}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}[n+r-2]a_nt^{n+r}=0$$

Equating the coefficient of $t^{r-1}$, the lowest power of $t$ to be zero, we obtain $r =0, \frac12$. Equating the coefficient of $t^{n+r}$ to be zero, we have: $$(2(n+r)(n+r+1)+n+r)a_{n+1}+(n+r-2)a_n=0$$ $$\implies a_{n+1}=\frac{-(n+r-2)a_n}{2(n+r)(n+r+1)+n+r}\,\,, n =0, 1, 2,…$$

Hope you can take it from here by considering the two different values of $r$.

Comment: You are saying to equate the coefficients of $t^{n+r}$ to zero, but in the equation you give, the second and the third term dont have the same power for $t$. Can you still equate the coefficients?

Comment: @K.Kamal Sorry, My bad...